# listing values from select box

Tags: jquery

I have a Select Box with multiple="multiple"

I want to list the text and not values of all selected items

How can i do it?

Comment: Is this related to jQuery? As it is tagged with that, but seems to be referring to a problem you are having with HTML

Comment: actually it's quite easy to do $("#multi").val() and fetch the selected values. However the same does not work for text  $("#multi").text()  returns an error

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work...

```
var foo = [];
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){
   foo[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```

Comment: @Satya: Glad if it helped you. it should work with selected though.